# Why does isKindOfClass:Nil return YES on __NSCFConstantString?

Tags: objective-c, nsobject

I encountered some code that might potentially use `Nil` as the class in an `isKindOfClass:` check and was curious what would happen in that case.  Using Xcode 6.2, with the OS X 10.10 SDK and running on 10.9.5:

```
for (id obj in @[
                 @"foo",
                 @"This is a long string.",
                 [NSString new],
                 [NSString stringWithUTF8String:"Hello, world!"],
                 [@"This is a constructed " stringByAppendingString:@"string."],
                 @YES,
                 @2015,
                 @[],
                 @[ @42, ],
                 @[ @"hello", ],
                 @{ @"hi": @5, },
                 ]) {
    NSLog(@"[obj className] => %@; [obj isKindOfClass:Nil] => %@", [obj className], [obj isKindOfClass:Nil] ? @"YES" : @"NO");
}
```

produces:

```
[obj className] => __NSCFConstantString; [obj isKindOfClass:Nil] => YES
[obj className] => __NSCFConstantString; [obj isKindOfClass:Nil] => YES
[obj className] => __NSCFConstantString; [obj isKindOfClass:Nil] => YES
[obj className] => __NSCFString; [obj isKindOfClass:Nil] => NO
[obj className] => __NSCFString; [obj isKindOfClass:Nil] => NO
[obj className] => __NSCFBoolean; [obj isKindOfClass:Nil] => NO
[obj className] => __NSCFNumber; [obj isKindOfClass:Nil] => NO
[obj className] => __NSArrayI; [obj isKindOfClass:Nil] => NO
[obj className] => __NSArrayI; [obj isKindOfClass:Nil] => NO
[obj className] => __NSArrayI; [obj isKindOfClass:Nil] => NO
[obj className] => __NSDictionaryI; [obj isKindOfClass:Nil] => NO
```

Why does `[obj isKindOfClass:Nil]` return `YES` for `__NSCFConstantString` objects and nothing else (or, at least, nothing else I've tried)?

***edit:*** Ultimately, the solution in the code I'm working on is to prevent the call from happening when the class is `Nil`, so this question is really just a curiosity, especially since the behavior is different on iOS 9.1 and OS X 10.11.1 (per the comments).

Comment: Interesting: yes, usefull: not so much. The first three are all constants created at compile-time, the others are created at run-time.

Comment: Good question… Another question: Why would you do `[obj isKindOfClass:Nil]`

Comment: FYI - Under iOS 9.1 the same code gives `NO` for all values.

Comment: All are `No` for OSX as well  under OSX 10.11.1, Xcode 7.1, 10.11 SDK.

Comment: And all are `NO` for OS X using Xcode 7.1 under 10.10.5. Might be an issue under OS X 10.9.

Comment: @vikingosegundo: The code is passing the result of another method call as the parameter for `isKindOfClass:` and that other method call can return `Nil`.  Basically, there's a missed error check, which I'm fixing, but curiosity got the better of me.

Comment: @vikingosegundo: It is necessary if the code is to work as intended on Xcode 6.2 + OS X, apparently.

Comment: Just send the method to a nil object. It is save. it will immediately return nil

Comment: [Here's the source for NSObject](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-532/runtime/NSObject.mm). Dig a little deeper and see why it's an issue under OS X 10.9.

Comment: @vikingosegundo The object on which `isKindOfClass:` is being called isn't `nil`; it's the `Class` parameter that's `Nil`, and seems to result in inconsistent behavior.

Comment: I still fail to see why you must secure it. can u post a code example?

Comment: @vikingosegundo: I have an `inputObject` and I'm getting the `expectedClass` for `inputObject` from some other source (based on the context, not `inputObject`).  If that lookup fails, `expectedClass` is `Nil` but (based on my above test) `[inputObject isKindOfClass:expectedClass]` might return `YES` where `inputObject` can't be of the expected class since we don't know what the expected class should be.

Comment: @rmaddy: It looks like `isKindOfClass:` is calling `class_getSuperclass`, defined in http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-532/runtime/objc-class.mm, which is calling `_class_getSuperclass`, declared in http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-532/runtime/objc-private.h, for which I don't think there's source?

Comment: @Isaac, this indeed sounds like a valid use case, but also like a fragile design.

Comment: Many framework methods have undefined results when passed nil/Nil (same thing).  You've managed to find one case where the undefined behavior actually changed.  Cool!